# Limits of Integral

Tags: integration

[image]

I'm studying joint distribution of 2 random variables and I want to calculate the area under x=y line (shadowed region). The equation is as follows: 
$$F_{xy}(x,y)= \int_D \int_\ f_{xy} \ (xy)dxdy $$

While choosing limits of integral how should I decide where x and y start and end. First I wrote limits as x -> minus infinity to y; y-> minus infinity to infinity. But in the book it is x-> minus infinity to infinity; y-> minus infinity to x. How can I understand which axis goes from minus infinity to infinity and which is from minus infinity to the line? I have encountered with similar examples (like area under x+y line) and always make mistakes. What is the rule for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter as long as the region parametrized is the same. The rule is to let one of your parameters to be free (the running parameter) the then force the other one to give you the the region. Specifically, focus on the boundary of the region, in this case $y=x$. Then at every point on $y=x$ you can integrate either in infinitesimal columns (going to $y=-\infty$) or infinitesimal rows (going to $x=+\infty$). So:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^x f(x,y)dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{y}^\infty f(x,y)dydx$$